# What is the interaction between electrons and the electromagnetic field to give them charge?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, quarks

***What is the interaction between a particle, like an electron, with the electromagnetic field that causes that particle to be charged?**
for example. If the positive charge of a proton comes from the amount of positively charged quarks that make it up, two up 1 down. then how do the quarks get charge?
**I cant find a good answer for this, people say things like "protons are charged positively because of the charge of the quarks that make them up, but say that charge is where electrons are, more electrons than protons and you get negative charge, and vis versa. but how do the electrons get there charge in the first place, thats when people don't make since. for protons, it was the quarks, but for electrons they say it was it interacting with the electromagnetic field.**
not to mention color charge.

Comment: This question is very hard to answer as it really depends on the level of theory you are looking at. E.g in Quantum field theory the answer boils down to the fact that there is a certain symmetry in the theory which results in a $U(1)$ gauge theory that is responsible for the electromagnetic charge. Though this just rewords the question as then you could ask why this is actually the relevant symmetry to look at.

Comment: PBS Spacetime actually did a video about this recently: https://youtu.be/esayi49OAk4

Comment: Alas! that video makes a ponderous hash of the explanation: lies to children (with pompous self-confidence, to boot!). It thinks it reduces charge to hypercharge (and isospin), insouciantly ignoring that the freaky hypercharge values assigned to particles are expressly *contrived* to yield their electric charges. GUTs reduce hypercharge to a deeper level, but these are speculative theories also constructed to accommodate these facts.  And I can't imagine the OP would stomach monopole arguments...

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> What is the interaction between electrons and the electromagnetic field to give them charge

Physics is a discipline where observations and measurements are modeled mathematically into theories that are descriptive and, important, predictive of new observations and measurements.

To get such theories, new axiomatic statements are assumed which pick up from the plethora of mathematical solutions those solutions that are descriptive and predictive. The electric charge on bodies and, in this case the particle electron, is one of the axiomatic assumptions in developing physics theories.

So the [charge of the electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge) is **assigned by the observers**, to the particle so that electrodynamics theory is consistent, descriptive and predictive, it is not generated by the interactions.

Now as with all axioms, one can make in a new mathematical theory an axiom into a theorem, and turn the theorem into an axiom. In the complicated mathematics of quantum electrodynamics charges become labels on the wave functions representing particles  and the rules of quantum field theory become the axioms.

This is mathematically convenient, even beautiful, and makes predictions for measurements simpler and easier. Within the theory one can say that the structure of the theory assigns the charges to the particles.

You ask:

> If the positive charge of a proton comes from the amount of positively charged quarks that make it up, two up 1 down. then how do the quarks get charge?

The assignment of electric charge to the quarks follows the same logic as with the charge assignment to the electron. Studying in accelerators interactions, the quark model fitted the observations and the data so the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) with its symmetries developed.

The [proton is much more complicated](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/) when going into quantum field theory but the same reasoning as with the electron holds. The assigned by experiment charges to the quarks become labels of the wavefunctions and the rules  of field theory become the axioms. It works in predicting experimental results.